# Maya python : TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I'm trying to make a little script for batch rending for maya and every time I have this error at the line `for i in xrange((startFrame)+"," +(endFrame) + int(1)):` :
 in Batch # `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found`

the code :

```
def Batch(ignore):
    # Settings
    startFrame = cmds.textField (myStart, query=True, text=True)
    endFrame   = cmds.textField (myEnd,   query=True, text=True)
    Camera     = cmds.textField (myCamera,query=True, text=True)

    for i in xrange((startFrame)+"," +(endFrame) + int(1)):
        maya.cmds.currentTime(i)
        mel.eval('execRmanMenuItem("Render");')
        editor = 'renderView'
```

I'll be very thankful if someone could help me.

Comment: `for i in xrange(startFrame, endFrame + 1):` ??

Comment: try .format() with {} that should coerce a type to string. if you're on python 3.6 f-strings do the same as .format() method. + are never good on strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `xrange` takes ints as parameters not strings,

This should solve it:

```
for i in xrange(int(startFrame), int(endFrame)+1):
    ...
```

Comment: @iobs, consider accepting the answer. Happy coding :)